# Store your events directly from kafka into database?, when or why using S3/HDFS before?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, transactions, streaming, distributed-system

I'm learning about event-streams/event pipelines.

I know how looks a normal (and simple) pipeline, let's say something like this, which is very easy to find in internet:

```
Kafka-> S3/HDFS/... -> database/datawarehouse
```

My question is the next, why I don't see this architecture?:

```
Kafka -> database/datawarehouse
```

I know why in my company we use S3 to store our events before going to db, but I just want some additional opinion or point of view as I didn't work so much in companies with event-streams pipelines
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the architectural diagram I have created:

[image]

> **Note:** Here, I am pushing data from Kafka to MongoDB, Hive and HBase

Comment: If it is not you intended, please let me know, so that I will delete this post !

Comment: really cool actually. Is not my intention, is just getting new options in my mind. I really love your diagram, make sense as well, thanks for such amazing visual resource

Answer (score 1):

Kafka has connectors, which should be leveraged if you just want to stream data from Kafka into other repositories (sink connector) or vice versa(source connector).

Check out the documentation here.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/connectors.html

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect